# How to get Spring Restful Service work with SSL?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, ssl

i have a RestService who gives me some Data from my Database. This works fine with spring rest stuff. Now i want to secure the service via SSL. Is there any option with spring ? I only want to secure the traffic and dont want to authentificate. Is that Possible?

Can someone give me a kickstart ? I'm very new to SSL Stuff.

The client sends a Post request where my data are described, that i need. 
The service is reading the needed Data and will send a response with that data as a json.

And i want to make this way go through SSL.

Comment: You will have to enable SSL on the application server on which you deploy the services.

Comment: ssl has nothing to do with authentification

Comment: yes, i know. Its a comment for the spring users. 
I even enabled the SSL stuff in the application Server. im using Tomcat 7. Thank you guys so far for your comments

Answer (score 0):

To install and configure SSL support on Tomcat, you need to follow these simple steps:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Maybe i didnt get the main thing about SSL. Do i have to configure my application server only?
So i dont have to do anything in my app self?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple places you can implement SSL. I would suggest you to install SSL that you want to expose to client on Web Server or the load balancer level like apache not on application server like tomcat if you want to scale your application, with multiple tomcat instances, having SSL certificate only on app server is not advisable.